# Unable to access Java application menu

Tags: applications, user-interface, java

After installing an application in java on the first run it worked normally, on the second run the application opens, but it is not possible to click on any option in the application menu.

This is the link that the application
https://downloads.prosysopc.com/opc-ua-simulation-server-downloads.php

Answer (score 0):

Try running the Java application from the console if you can, because often errors like that are displayed on stdout or stderror.